# How to zip the list tempfiles with rubyzip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, ruby-on-rails-4, rubyzip

I have a list of tempfiles like this:

```
urls = [#<Tempfile:/tmp/down20190222-7434-18yoxw4.jpg>, #<Tempfile:/tmp/down20190222-7434-1r8c4y2.jpg>, #<Tempfile:/tmp/down20190222-7434-qpyiy1.JPG>, #<Tempfile:/tmp/down20190222-7434-q8xyup.mp4>]
```

now I want to zip these files for users to download it:

```
t = Tempfile.new('tmp-zip')
Zip::OutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|
  urls.each do |file|
    zos.print IO.read(file)
  end
end

send_file t.path, :type => "application/zip", :filename => "myfile.zip"

t.close
```

but I got the error `closed stream excluded from capture: DSN not set`
at the line: `zos.print IO.read(file)`. What was I wrong in this case?
This is my full code:

```
if posts.present?
      urls = []
      posts.each do |post|
        urls << post.filestack_image_url if post.filestack_image_url.present?
        urls << post.photo_attributes('original')['url'] if post.photo.present?
        urls << post.filestack_video_url if post.filestack_video_url.present?
        urls << post.video_attributes('remote')['url'] if post.video.present?
      end

      urls = urls.collect {|url| download_url(url) }.compact

      t = Tempfile.new('tmp-zip')
      Zip::OutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|
        urls.each do |file|
          zos.print IO.read(file.path.to_s.split("/")[-1])
        end
      end

      send_file t.path, :type => "application/zip", :filename => "Awesome.zip"

      t.close
end
```

Comment: are those files still there? have you checked they can be read? what is the full stacktrace?

Comment: @phoet yes the files still there and they can be read,